# Custom ListView Adapter from Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

I would like to list some user data that I getting from `FireBase` as name, age, Gender and Birthday. I have a `FireBase` listener and the list have to refresh every-time the database is changed.

This is how I sent data to the adapter

```
    private void list(String Name){
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUser);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    mUser.add(Name,Age,Gender,Birthday);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is the layout I want to list

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNameList"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textAgeList"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="Age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textBirthdayList"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="Birthday"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textGenderList"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="gender"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


   </RelativeLayout>
```

If possible I would like to list and Image from database too.

Comment: Use addValueEvent listner it will listen every changes happen in that node
`ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {}`

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is the ListView adapter to show the data

Comment: you have to initialize this `final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUser);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);` 
outside, and only the new values from the data base add to the 
list `mUser.add(Name,Age,Gender,Birthday);`
then set `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: But I would like to show in one row all the detail(Name,Age,Gender,Birthday) for ever single user, that way It show in each row one details, I need a custom Adapter that allow me to show more than one String.

Answer (score 0):

get child data from snapshot and parse to model class as given below and add to arraylist.

```
    @Override
        public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot snapshot){

            ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Student student = postSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                studentList.add(student);
            }
            //use custom adapter here.
        }
```

for more reference for custom adapter to arralist model class in recycler view,refer the below link
        https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/